# Three.js prevent Raycast through Gui

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I want to select objects with raycasting, but everytime i want to select something on the three.js gui, the Mousdownevent get triggered.
How can i say something like "if the Gui is in front of the object, dont trigger"

`document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
if (event){}`

the gui is a normal three.js gui made like this:

```
gui = new GUI( { width: 330 } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with `jQuery` and an additional control variable:

```js
$( gui.domElement ).mouseenter(function(evt) {

    enableRaycasting = false;

} );

$( gui.domElement ).mouseleave(function() {

    enableRaycasting = true;

} );
```

You can then use `enableRaycasting` in order to determine if raycasting should happen.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gnwz5ae7/

Comment: This was very helpful, but there's still an issue:
If a dropdown menu of the dat.gui is too big and not in the area of the gui.domElement anymore, sometimes (not everytime) raycast will be enabled.